# Reactjs, Cannot read property 'lessons' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code I tell the API to retrieve the data from the end point inside `componentDidMount()`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      lessons: API.getAllLessons()
    })
  }
```

Then I map each item inside the list to an individual panel inside the render

```
render() {
    return (
    this.state.lessons.map((lesson)=>{
        <LessonItem lesson={lesson}/>
    })
    );
  }
```

However, it throws an error when mapping as the property in the state it's trying to map is null, but it shouldn't be as data is returned from the API.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'lessons' of null

My state gets defined like so

```
export interface AuthenticatedHomeState {
  currentUser: any;
  lessons: any;
}
```

Comment: does `getAllLessons` return a `Promise`?

Comment: I am unsure how to tell for sure but I think it does, yes.

Comment: `this.state.lessons` is null until `componentDidMount`, so at first render, it is `null`, unless you set a default, like `this.state = { lessons: [] }`

Comment: I don't use a classic constructor, I have updated to try and reflect this. implementing a constructor only makes it complain about lessons being readonly

Comment: Post the full component code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably didn't initialised the state.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    lessons: [] //default value
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      lessons: API.getAllLessons()
    })
}
```

However, if API.getAllLessons returns a Promise you will need to handle it differently.

Comment: Yeah, what this guy said.

Comment: I would usually do this but the project I am working on does it completely different. I have updated the post to show you how my state is handled.

Comment: As soon as I implement the constructor it complains that lessons is readonly

Answer (score 0):

you are calling componentDidMount, meaning it will run after render had been called. You need to call componentWillMount()

Answer (score 0):

You have to intialise the state first, then call the api, and if the api call is a promise call(which usually is) you will have to read the values in such a way,

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    lessons: [] //set default value for lessons
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
    API.getAllLessons().then((resp)=>{
      this.setState({
        lessons: resp.data
      })
    })
}
```